# JQuery JSONP ajax not calling

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, yelp

i'm trying to use yelp v2 js api.

when I try to trigger ajax call from form event, success is not fired (and nothing in firebug NET panel)  I can step thru debugger to $.ajax line fine...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
            .
            .
            .

            $.ajax({
                'type': 'GET',
                'url': message.action,
                'data': parameterMap,
                'cache': true,
                'dataType': 'jsonp',
                'jsonp': false,
                'jsonpCallback': 'cb',
                'success': cbSuccess
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

however, when I run same code on page load (strip out wrapper $('#btnSubmit').click(function() from above code) it works fine.
why is this?

Comment: Is error event triggered? What message?

Comment: Where is the function "cb" defined?  It could be an issue with scope

Comment: cb is global function I left out here just to simplify.  It works fine under second scenario above.  I had same problem when I defined it inside ajax call as 'success' parameter.

Comment: no error is triggered that I can tell (not showing in console at least) no message. no evidence request was sent.

Comment: i changed parameter dataType to 'json_callback' and clear cache, reload page and I see the request go out, but I get empty response.  I think this problem is related to caching.  However yelp server gives back error if caching is turned off.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm experiencing something similar. I am attempting to make several Yelp API v2 calls in succession and, every time, one of the calls randomly fails. The network tab in Chrome proves that each calls succeeds (200) and each response is cb({...}) - I'm using the same callback name - but, I've added 'error' function/handlers and, for one of the 200s, I'll get a "parserror" and the error message is "cb was not called". An implementation of the callback (cb) appears unnecessary but I added one anyway and it simply logs itself to the console. 'cb' is never called.